# Is it wrong to attend iftar at a masjid if I am not fasting?

Tags: iftar

Is is wrong on my part to eat at an iftar feast arranged by a Masjid if am not on fast?

However the food is more than enough for everybody.

Comment: When I was younger and not old enough to fast, I went to a Masjid iftar and ate it even though I wasn't fasting.

Comment: The idea behind these iftars is not to feed people rather than to let people get together and get to know each other it is for community building purpose!